# ¿Como multiplico todos los numero menos el de cada indice de un vector?

Tags: python, array

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo y necesito que La primera línea contiene un número entero T que indica el número de casos de prueba. Cada caso de prueba consta de dos líneas, la primera línea de cada caso de prueba contiene un número N que indica el tamaño del vector y la segunda línea contiene N códigos separados por espacios.
Para cada caso de prueba debe imprimir los N códigos cifrados que se necesitan para acceder a la bóveda, uno en cada línea

**EJ:
ENTRADA:**

1

5

10 3 5 6 2

**SALIDA:**

180 600 360 300 900

**EXPLICACION**

En este ejemplo, cuando i=0, se calcula el producto de todos los elementos del arreglo excepto Vector[0] el resultado es 180 (3 x 5 x 6 x 2). Cuando i=1 el resultado es 600 (10 x 5 x 6 x 2). Cuando i=2 el resultado es 360 (10 x 3 x 6 x 2). Cuando i=3 el resultado es 300 (10 x 3 x 5 x 2). Cuando i=4 el resultado es 900 (10 x 3 x 5 x 6)

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np
T = int(input())
N = int(input())
for i in range(T):
      Vector = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(Vector)
print(np.prod(Vector))
```

No se como hacer para multiplicar todos los valores excepto el indice siguiendo el orden como en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que pides tuve que hacer:

> Nota no use panda.

- Agregé dos bucles que corre hasta llegar a la variable `N` para crear el patron que quieres.
- El if lo usamos para ver si debemos o nó multipricarlo deacuerdo a esta simpre operacion `i_1!=i_2`.
- En el primer bucle inicialisé la variable `codigo` para multipricar todo los elementos excepto cuando coincidan los dos indices.

Codigo:

```Python
T = int(input())
N = int(input())

for y in range(T):
    Vector=list( 
 map(int, input().split()));
    for i_1 in range(N):
        codigo=1;
        for num in Vector:
            codigo*=num if Vector.index(num) != i_1 else 1;
        print(codigo,end=" ");
    print();#\n
```

### Enlaces:

[Ejecutar codigo en tio.run](https://tio.run/##bY/BDsFAEIbv8xS/unRFRFsUzb6Ck7ggIhSbsLupdfD0NWsbDTF7mfzzzZdZ@3QXo7O6XkJCaRcrbR8uFoIWvwGdTIUnZ6j2@lzGSzEncK3KgzOVvKq7i0G47S3vuD6axcHdXpUXiOKNe4vaJa1n0Xh8HcxRnY1Mik8S8PQ/7kudvK4jGfoetL6eDDeumdm2alv5/wWkX@qjjBA1R4aRKLobXdc5jSkZIsMYE6SUIryMuyz0n2xEU8w4HYFXPMPdhHL4lBVp8gI)

Comment: @Sam ... Si tienes dudas me pides expricacion, pero por favor a la proxima mas esfuerso por hacer el ejercicio que la persona que te lo puso lo hace para que tú aprendas a resolver problemas con python y no solo aprendas su sintaxis.